# 1px glitch in jQuery slider in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, visual-glitch

I'm using a slider from jQuery UI where each tickmark is 1px wide.

This is how it looks in Firefox and Safari:

[image]

This is right.

But this is how it looks in Chrome:

[image]
[image]

This is a weird glitch unique to Chrome. I've tried `box-sizing` and `box-shadow` after looking at similar questions, but I haven't had success in making these tickmarks appear right.

If I set it to 2px:

[image]

All tickmarks show up but it's still glitchy.

In case the code is needed:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

JS:

```
function createSlider() {
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 1,
        max: numOfPages * 3, 
        step: 1, 
        range: false,
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        create: function(event, ui) { 
            setSliderTicks(event.target);
        }
    });
}

function setSliderTicks(){
    var $slider =  $('#slider');
    var max =  $slider.slider("option", "max");    
    var spacing =  100 / (max - 1);
    console.log('Spacing: ' + spacing);

    $slider.find('.tickmark').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < max ; i++) {
        $('<span class="tickmark"></span>').css('left', (spacing * i) +  '%').appendTo($slider); 
     }
}
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: ;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 3px;
    width: 75%;

}

.ui-slider {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 6px;
    top: 50%;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
    width: 19px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #ededed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.ui-slider-handle:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.tickmark {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #ededed;
    height: 12px;
    position:absolute;
    top: -150%;
}
```

The slider is from https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: could you link the slider your're using?

Comment: Updated my question @alfredopacino

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to reproduce your issue, I made a jsfiddle and looks fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/alfredopacino/p5khfe2m/
Could you tell if you're facing that problem in my jsfiddle too?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your JS fiddle :( I'm still playing around with it to see what it might be. Could it be that JSfiddle renders things differently than Chrome?

Comment: It's more likely some other css rule (you didn't post) is messing up the slider render

Comment: Shot in the dark, what if you replace `width: 1px;
` with `border-left: 1px solid #fff;`?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce my entire code in your jsfiddle but having difficulty. And sorry -- that border-left results in the same appearance

Comment: What if you add below `width:1px` this line `outline: 1px solid transparent;` OR this `box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0);`

Comment: Those lines don't work either D: I put all my HTML and CSS on your jsfiddle. It looks fine there. I'm trying to look up if JSfiddle renders things differently than Chrome. I'm running this site locally via Nodejs if that helps.

Comment: what's the value of `numOfPages`?

Comment: 10, you had it right

Comment: wait, you don't have a zoom different than 100% in your page, right?

Comment: 80% zoom :/ I’ve seen those issues with Chrome zoom and 1px width - but I can’t find if they’ve been solved?

Comment: `border-left: thin white solid;` works